# How to control layer ordering in Virtual Earth

Tags: javascript, virtual-earth

I have a mapping application that needs to draw a path, and then display icons on top of the path. I can't find a way to control the order of virtual earth layers, other than the order in which they are added.

Does anyone know how to change the z index of Virtual Earth shape layers, or force a layer to the front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to iterate through the shapes in your VEShapeLayer and use the [VEShape.SetZIndex method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb877869.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JQuery you can use the following

```
        $('#' + yourlayer.iid).children(".VEAPI_Pushpin").css('zIndex', 2000);
```

...remember that the default zIndex for a VEShape is 1000